# Div row-fluid does not work in Django and Twitter-Bootstrap

Tags: django, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Django and Twitter-Bootstrap to create the layout, but the row div fluid in the template does not work.
I'm using inheritance templates and tried placing the div in children templates but does not work.
What should happen is resizing the page according to the resolution of the browser.
This is an example:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html#

The structure may be:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3"></div>
<div class="span9"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

base.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
{% block sidebarnav %} {% endblock sidebarnav %}
{% block content %} {% endblock content %}  
</div>  
</div>
```

base_profile.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}     
{% block sidebarnav %} {% endblock sidebarnav %}
{% block content %} {% endblock content %}
```

base_home.html

```
{% extends "base_profile.html" %}
{% block sidebarnav %} 
<div class="span3">
<div class="well sidebar-nav">
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="nav-header">Home</li>
    <li class="{% active request '/home/' %}"><a href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li> 
    <li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
 </div>
</div>
{% endblock sidebarnav %}

{% block content %} {% endblock content %}
```

index_home.html

```
{% extends "base_home.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="span9">
content
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

With this structure the fluid div row appears in firebug but does not work to resize the layout as the resolution of the browser. Thanks!

EDIT(solution):

Need the file responsive to works perfectly.

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already figured this out, but [what you were missing were the responsive media queries](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive):

> Bootstrap doesn't automatically include these media queries, but understanding and adding them is very easy and requires minimal setup. You have a few options for including the responsive features of Bootstrap:
>
> 1. Use the compiled responsive version, bootstrap-responsive.css
> 2. Add @import "responsive.less" and recompile Bootstrap
> 3. Modify and recompile responsive.less as a separate file